# jquery delegating ui button assign

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

What's the right syntax for assign `ui` `.button` using delegating with `.on` method?

I tried w/o success this kind of construction:

```
$("body").on("load","a.button",function(){ $("a.button").button(); });
```

Verbally: After page is loaded turn each .button class element to graphic mode using ui .button method. Including dynamic loaded content.

Comment: So what event you're listening to? Adding element to DOM?

Comment: .button() method only turns inputs to graphics mode. (immediately after page load)

Comment: ok. But what event you're attaching to? What is "load"?

Comment: Verbally: After page is loaded turn each .button class element to graphic mode using ui .button method. Including dynamic loaded content.

Comment: "Including dynamic loaded content" vs "After page is loaded" --- these two events occur in different time. At first you have your page loaded, and after, possible even 10 hours (?) some dynamic element could be loaded.

Comment: Zerkms is right, if you are using dynamic objets you have to verify if the objects exists or on the dynamic objects are loaded into to page (diferent of page is loaded)

Comment: Question is related to jquery.delegating. I believe its accurate determination then.

Comment: Don't know why someone would downvote this. This is certainly a real question, even though it's somewhat vague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When delegating, your handler is bound to the event of the parent element (`body`), which on trigger will look for any elements matching your selector (`a.button`) within itself.

This is why your example doesn't work since there's no event for DOM insertion/mutation (the `load` event does not work like that). You will have to trigger `.button()` on the elements yourself after insertion.

If you want to be fancy and use custom events to handle any updates of dynamically inserted content, you could do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Custom event listener to update the content on demand
var container = $("#container").on("update", function() {
    // Turn any a.button elements into jQuery UI buttons
    $("a.button", container).button();
});

// Get some content
$.get("/foo", function(html) {
    // Insert content to container and trigger an update
    container.html(html).trigger("update");
});
```

*Notice: I added the container element for a clearer demonstration. This will work without it, and directly on `document.body` if you prefer.*

If you want to trigger the custom `update` event on load, just add `container.trigger("update")` to your document ready.

Comment: Thats it. Thank you for your time and enthusiasm for deep explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
$(function() {
    $( "input:submit, a, button", ".demo" ).button();

    // Original example method
//    $( "a", ".demo" ).click(function() { return false; });

    // on(), if you're not loading the targets after page-load
//    $( "a", ".demo" ).on ("click", function() { return false; });

    // on(), if you are loading the targets after page-load
    $( document ).on ("click", "a, .demo", function() { return false; });
});​
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/FG6rd/